# Heroku app deployment error(code: H12)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, cloud9-ide, mlab

I'm trying to deploy a simple blogging app but seem to have run into a problem. I'm using mlab for my production database and I am using a local mongodb database for development purposes. I'm using cloud9 as my development IDE. When I deploy, it shows an application error. Heroku logs show this:

```
    mirror006:~/workspace/BlogApp (master) $ heroku logs
    2017-08-13T19:32:50.692745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2017-08-13T19:32:50.693051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2017-08-13T19:32:52.983596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2017-08-13T19:32:56.362856+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-13T19:32:56.362881+00:00 app[web.1]: > Blogapp@1.0.0 start /app
    2017-08-13T19:32:56.362882+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
    2017-08-13T19:32:56.362883+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-13T19:32:57.556945+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2017-08-13T19:33:27.770082+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=3369d1d9-aae8-4e7e-8def-44f758f23106 fwd="59.144.74.12" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30002ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
    2017-08-13T19:53:46.895106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=5785fa66-24ce-4cc1-85f5-acdb6ca864a8 fwd="59.144.74.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
    2017-08-13T20:03:49.714563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=7c99aba8-76c7-470d-9331-5ee60a24fc5d fwd="59.144.74.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
    2017-08-13T20:03:50.447362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2017-08-13T20:03:50.448024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2017-08-13T20:03:51.264283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2017-08-13T20:03:51.413037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2017-08-13T21:26:37.020422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2017-08-13T21:26:37.020702+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2017-08-13T21:26:38.846640+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
    2017-08-13T21:26:42.380277+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-13T21:26:42.380294+00:00 app[web.1]: > Blogapp@1.0.0 start /app
    2017-08-13T21:26:42.380295+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
    2017-08-13T21:26:42.380296+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-13T21:26:44.422496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2017-08-13T21:27:16.098656+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=cb00d450-8000-4063-9c39-9ddee315fd7c fwd="59.144.74.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
    2017-08-13T21:40:37.976109+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=62411431-4eee-4c83-a2b0-55c21722e144 fwd="59.144.74.12" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
    2017-08-13T21:43:34.584453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=dd7856dc-03ab-442c-beb0-ff5ef81dd257 fwd="59.144.74.12" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https    
    2017-08-15T12:0

8:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mirrorpage06@gmail.com
    2017-08-15T12:08:50.215267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2017-08-15T12:08:50.216240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2017-08-15T12:08:49.662570+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user mirrorpage06@gmail.com
    2017-08-15T12:08:49.662570+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 6f0fe59d by user mirrorpage06@gmail.com
    2017-08-15T12:08:50.836753+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2017-08-15T12:08:50.995578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2017-08-15T12:08:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2017-08-15T12:08:56.246690+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-15T12:08:56.246707+00:00 app[web.1]: > Blogapp@1.0.0 start /app
    2017-08-15T12:08:56.246708+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
    2017-08-15T12:08:56.246708+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2017-08-15T12:08:57.857492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2017-08-15T12:08:59.112233+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=3e3fbea2-9cc5-47f6-9471-eab61796b768 fwd="169.149.194.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=47ms status=302 bytes=249 protocol=https
    2017-08-15T12:09:29.493928+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/blogs" host=immense-river-27381.herokuapp.com request_id=6a70f92e-bdf8-4e29-9e3c-0bb7b7e76b57 fwd="169.149.194.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: Did you check your handler for `/blogs`? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout

Comment: I think you need error handling for uncaught errors.

Comment: I don't know what fixed it but I deleted my database and recreated  a new one and everything seems to work fine now.